# Tuning density in Gelfand-Dey estimator (Reciprocal Importance Sampling) of Marginal Likelihood

Tags: bayesian, estimation, likelihood, computational-statistics, marginal-distribution

If *y* denotes the data and *(t,L)* denotes set of parameters, then the marginal likelihood is

[image]

Here, [image] is a proper prior, *f(y|t,L)* denotes the (conditional) likelihood, *m(y)* is used to denote the marginal likelihood of data *y* and *g(t,L)* is a proper tuning density for the parameter *t* and *L*. The Gelfand-Dey estimator of marginal likelihood is expressed as

[image]

, where [image] is set of MCMC draws from posterior distribution [image].  [Reference : Gelfand and Dey (1994)]

Now *t* has a support on [image] and *L* has support over the permutation space of {1,2,...,*M*}. Here *M* is a positive integer (e.g.,  M = 200, 300 etc). Tuning density *g(t,L)* can be assumed as [image] and prior [image] can be assumed as [image].

**Question:**

1. I am struggling to fix a tuning density for *L*. Can anybody please help me in this ?
2. I have assumed a discrete uniform prior for *L* over the permutation space of {1,2,...,*M*}. Is there any better alternative ?
3. If possible, can you suggest me some other method of marginal likelihood estimation to tackle this problem ?